# C++ understanding iter and erase

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am just looking at a code, and I must say that I don't fully understand it yet.

```
vector<long>::iterator iter1;
vector<long>::iterator iter2;

while(m_vPitchMarks[0]<=vPitchPeriode[0])
{
    iter1 = m_vPitchMarks.begin();
    iter2 = vPitchPeriode.begin();

    m_vPitchMarks.erase(iter1);
    vPitchPeriode.erase(iter2);
    if((m_vPitchMarks.size()==0)||(vPitchPeriode.size()==0))
        break;
}
```

I am trying to break it down:

Here we will do a while-statement while the value of the first element of m_vPitchMarks is smaller than the value of the first element of vPitchPeriod.

```
while(m_vPitchMarks[0]<=vPitchPeriode[0])
{
}
```

Here we set something like a reference to the first element (element at index [0]) of both vectors.

```
iter1 = m_vPitchMarks.begin();
iter2 = vPitchPeriode.begin();
```

Now we erase all elements from m_vPitchMarks<> that have just this value. 
For example, if iter1 had a value of 15, all elements in m_vPitchMarks<> that also have the value of 15 will be deleted, and the vector becomes shortened.

```
m_vPitchMarks.erase(iter1);
vPitchPeriode.erase(iter2);
```

Is that correct?
Thank you.

Comment: This code looks like it should be a call to `std::mismatch` and a couple range-`erase` calls.

Comment: @davmac: the iterators don't get used after the erase anyway.  However, if either of the containers is empty at the start, then the first test the `while` does will be UB.  It's not evident from the posted code whether or not that is a possible scenario.

Comment: @davmac not really the next use of the iterators after the erase is to reassign them afresh.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ah, right. Misread it.

Answer (score 2):

Almost as you say this:

```
while(m_vPitchMarks[0]<=vPitchPeriode[0])
```

will loop while the first value of `m_vPitchMarks` is less than **or equal** to the first value of `vPitchPeriode`.

Your explanation for this this code:

```
    iter1 = m_vPitchMarks.begin();
    iter2 = vPitchPeriode.begin();

    m_vPitchMarks.erase(iter1);
    vPitchPeriode.erase(iter2);
```

is not quite right. It simply removes the first value from both the vectors.

If you were using a `std::deque` or a `std::list` instead then you would just call `pop_front` to get the same result.

Then if we're out of values stop looping:

```
    if((m_vPitchMarks.size()==0)||(vPitchPeriode.size()==0))
        break;
```

Seems a particularly inefficient route given erasing an element from the front of a vector requires shifting every element that is left.

Comment: So m_vPitchMarks.Resize(0) (or m_vPitchMarks.Clear()) would do the same?

Comment: @tmighty, no, the `erase` call is only removing the elements being referred to by `iter1` and `iter2`. All other elements remain intact. `resize(0)` or `clear()` would remove **all** elements.

Comment: @tmighty, a really shortened description of the code is "while the first element of `m_vPitchMarks` is less than or equal to the first element of `vPitchPeriode`, remove the first element from each. If neither are empty, repeat"